# Minikube horizontal pod autoscaling error: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-scaling, google-kubernetes-engine

I'v enabled heapster on minikube

```
minikube addons start heapster
```

And custom metrics with

```
minikube start --extra-config kubelet.EnableCustomMetrics=true
```

My deployment looks like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kubia
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: kubia
      labels:
        app: kubia
      annotations:
        pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[
            {
                "name": "setup",
                "image": "busybox",
                "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                "command": ["sh", "-c", "echo \"{\\\"endpoint\\\": \\\"http://$POD_IP:8080/metrics\\\"}\" > /etc/custom-metrics/definition.json"],
                "env": [{
                  "name": "POD_IP",
                  "valueFrom": {
                    "fieldRef": {
                      "apiVersion": "v1",
                      "fieldPath": "status.podIP"
                    }
                  }
                }],
                "volumeMounts": [
                    {
                        "name": "config",
                        "mountPath": "/etc/custom-metrics"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]'
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: luksa/kubia:qps
        name: nodejs
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/custom-metrics
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
      volumes:
      - name: config
        emptyDir:
```

My hpa looks like

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: kubia
  annotations:
    alpha/target.custom-metrics.podautoscaler.kubernetes.io: '{"items":[{"name":"qps", "value": "20"}]}'
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: kubia
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 1000000
```

However I get target unknown

```
jonathan@ubuntu ~> kubectl get hpa
NAME      REFERENCE          TARGETS                MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
kubia     Deployment/kubia   <unknown> / 1000000%   1         5         1          31m
```

And the following warnings from the hpa

```
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       27m (x12 over 33m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from heapster
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  27m (x12 over 33m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from heapster
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `limit` on the resources and not only a request? Not 100% sure but it might be required in order for HPA to work

Comment: I'd read on another question that it's not but let me just try it

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: You can check [this workaround](https://github.com/Azure/ACS/issues/49#issuecomment-322098955)  which might help you resolve the issue. Can you check and let us know?

Comment: @whites11 I did, the stats show up after several minutes

Comment: my custom metrics are what I'm having an issue with now but I'll open another question on that

Comment: @Taher I'm running on Minikube and have the addon-manager installed. The issue seems to go away after several minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the `metrics-server` addons is enabled on minikube.

When I start minikube () I have the following addons enabled by default:

```
$ minikube addons list
- addon-manager: enabled
- coredns: disabled
- dashboard: enabled
- default-storageclass: enabled
- efk: disabled
- freshpod: disabled
- heapster: enabled
- ingress: disabled
- kube-dns: enabled
- metrics-server: disabled
- registry: disabled
- registry-creds: disabled
- storage-provisioner: enabled
```

Enable the metrics server and HPAs appear to work great.

```
$ minikube addons enable metrics-server
metrics-server was successfully enabled
```

Answer (score 3):

> `metrics-server` monitoring needs to be deployed in the cluster to
>   provide metrics via the resource metrics API, as Horizontal Pod
>   Autoscaler uses this API to collect metrics.

Thus enable `metrics-server` addon via;

```
$ minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

Refer - [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler Walkthrough - Before you begin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#before-you-begin)